# I want Cypress to check that a specific list appears in the drop down

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a drop down element and I want to check that all of the text values appear in drop down list.   This syntax is passing even I change the last value to a value that's not appearing in the list so I know its not working. I want it to fail if one of the values doesn't appear as apposed to any of the values. Does anyone know how I alter it please

```js
export function check_f_e_Script_History_Status() {
            cy.get('#emvScriptHistory > .ng-isolate-scope > .panel > :nth-child(1) > .form-horizontal > .form-group > :nth-child(2) > .form-control')
            //.find("button")
            .each($button => expect($button.text()).to.satisfy(text => {
            return text.includes('0 Undefined')  ||        
             text.includes('1 (Pending)') ||
             text.includes('2 (Sent)') ||
             text.includes('3 (Deployed)') ||
             text.includes('4 (Failed - will retry)') ||
             text.includes('5 (Failed - will not retry)') ||
             text.includes('6 (Reverted)') ||
             text.includes('7 (Deprecated)')
            })
```

Comment: Your test currently expresses the requirement "every element has at least one of these labels", not "every one of these labels appears on exactly one element".

Comment: Hi John ,  Thank you for your response,   do you know how i can change it to every one of these labels appears on exactly one element